# Error You are not permitted to use that link to directly access that page

Tags: joomla-3.x, error-handling

I have a problem with Joomla! and I don't know how to solve it.

I have a lot of articles, about 1500. When I try to open multiple articles in order to edit them, I receive one of these errors on random articles:

**Error You are not permitted to use that link to directly access that page (article_id).**

If I close the tab and reopen the article it works fine.

It's not about logout and log back in. In order to replicate the problem, try to open multiple articles one after the other (CTRL + Click). Not all articles, but some of the will throw this error.

I don't know what might be the problem and it gets annoying.

Comment: Welcome Mihai, please take our [tour] while you wait for feedback.  Please consolidate this account with your https://stackoverflow.com/users/14712527/fotea-mihai account.  You should not have more than one account in the Stack Exchange network.  https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/18232/352329

Comment: I think this might be a bug in Joomla and might be associated with race conditions associated with Joomla setting 'edit ids'. You can see code related to this functionality in libraries/src/MVC/Controller/BaseController.php. In the checkEditId() function in that source code file it logs info to the log file, so if you switch JDEBUG on, do what you do to make it fail, then have a look in the log file, you might find a negative result when it's checking the edit id.